# How do I truncate a field data in an email?

Tags: visualforce, apex

I have an visual force email template that is looking at email conversation and so including email body as a 'note' in an email notification to the Support team that needs to be made aware of the 'note'  The issue is though that the email trail will include the compnay's email disclaimer and so I would like to remove this.  So I need to truncate or trim the data in the field (which will always be the same) from right to left xxx to yyy.

So to put into context

[image]

Teh template looks like this:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Task # (Ref:TA:{!relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__taskId__c}) has been updated by Email" recipientType="User" relatedToType="BMCServiceDesk__TaskHistory__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
<body>
<h2><i>Task # {!relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__taskId__c} has been updated by Email</i> </h2>
<br></br>
&nbsp;<b>Update: </b> {!relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__note__c}<br/>
<br></br>
&nbsp;<a href="https://eu2.salesforce.com/{!relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__FKWO__r.Id}">Task Link</a>  <br/>
<br></br>
&nbsp;<b>Regards,<br></br>
&nbsp;IT Service Desk</b>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

It is line 7 that I need to truncate -  **Update:**  {!relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__note__c}

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Sonya

Answer (score 1):

If the text you want to remove is of fixed length (I've guessed 345 below; you'll need to work out the length) then these Visualforce [functions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) LEFT and LEN should work:

```
{!LEFT(relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__note__c, LEN(relatedto.BMCServiceDesk__note__c) - 345)}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much I thought it might be something like this rather than a trigger as suggested:
01 trigger truncateDisclaimerData on Task(before insert, before update){
02      
03    for(Task tsk : trigger.new){
04          
05       if(tsk.BMCServiceDesk_Note__c != null && tsk.BMCServiceDesk_Note__c != ''){
06          pattern unusedpattern    = pattern.compile('Record link for BMC Remedyforce(?s)(.*)viruses.');
07          tsk.BMCServiceDesk_Note__c= unusedpattern.matcher(tsk.BMCServiceDesk_Note__c).replaceAll('');
08       }
09  
10    }
11  
12 }

Comment: @SonyaDhand Using a trigger is perfectly reasonable too and gets rid of the trailing information for any use of the field. Two downsides: 1) if the footer is missing from some emails or changes you will be chopping off part of the real message and losing it for good; 2) triggers must have test written (which is generally a good thing in my view but some people resent).